# svn:externals : Having more than one external repository in a local directory

Tags: svn, svn-externals

Is it possible to have 2 (or more) external repositories linked to a local directory ?

For example, I have a file named externals and containing :

```
http://somewhere/dev/trunk/F01common.lib include
```

I declare my property like that :

```
svn propset svn:externals -F ../external .
```

If I try to use a file like the one after, only the last line is taken :

```
http://somewhere/dev/trunk/F01common.lib include
http://somewhere/dev/trunk/F04logger.lib include
```

Is what I want to do possible or not ?
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc says it's possible: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html

Each external must be written on its line:

> Because the svn:externals property has a multiline value, we strongly
>   recommend that you use **svn propedit** instead of svn propset.